# What is the best approach to authorize a web API

Tags: php, web-services, jwt

There is an existing code base in core php (no framework). The APIs were also working with our any token. We are now introducing JWT tokens. Rather than adding a check on each API file that if the token is valid or not. The basic approach is to call a function on start of each file to check if the token is valid. I am wondering  if i can use some good practice and less hectic

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach is to write a middleware on request, each request has to pass through the middleware.

You can check out this website for some idea. 
[PSR 7 middlewares](http://weierophinney.github.io/2015-10-20-PSR-7-and-Middleware/#/)